# Different generators added to the same dictionary return the same values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

I have just encountered a weird Python (3.7.0) behavior which I don't really understand and looks like a bug for me. I want to create a dictionary with generators, but somehow all of them return the same values. Here is a code example of what I am talking about:

```
import itertools

d = {
"a": [-1, 2],
"b": [1, 2],
"c": [20, 20]
}
g = dict()
g2 = dict()
for letter, values in d.items():
    g[letter] = (values[0] * values[1] * x for x in itertools.count())
    g2[letter] = [values[0] * values[1] * x for x in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    for l, v in g.items():
        print(v.__next__())
print(g2)
```

From my point of view, expected output would be the same for g2 elements and g generators, however I always receive values from the latest generator:

```
0
0
0
400
400
400
800
800
800
{'a': [0, -2, -4], 'b': [0, 2, 4], 'c': [0, 400, 800]}
```

To conclude, am I doing something wrong? Or is it just a standard Python behavior?

Comment: What are you expecting as output? Also use the builtin `next`, do not call `o.__next__` explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is not due to generators. It's a scoping error.

In your generator declaration, you use the name `values`, although the generator is not executed until *after* the loop is done where `values` is now the last item in the list. Here is an example that reproduces your error.

```
for i in [1]:
    g = (i for _ in range(3))

i = 'some new value'

print(next(g)) # 'some new value'
```

In other words `values[0]` and `values[1]` were not bound to the generator and if the value behind the name `values` changes then so will the generators outputs.

This means you want a closure around your generator to store the values `values[0]` and `values[1]`. You can do that by defining your generator as a function.

```
import itertools

# Here is a function taht will return a generator
def gen(a, b):
    for x in itertools.count():
        yield a * b * x

d = {"a": [-1, 2], "b": [1, 2], "c": [20, 20]}

g, g2 = dict(), dict()

for letter, values in d.items():
    g[letter] = gen(values[0], values[1])
    g2[letter] = [values[0] * values[1] * x for x in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    for l, v in g.items():
        print(next(v))

print(g2)
```

In fact, inline generators are rarely used for that reason. Favor the `def-yield` way of creating generators.

Also, do no call `__next__`, use the builtin `next` instead.

### Output

```
0
0
0
-2
2
400
-4
4
800
{'a': [0, -2, -4], 'b': [0, 2, 4], 'c': [0, 400, 800]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out a fixed version of your code:

```
import itertools

def make_generator(values):
    return (values[0] * values[1] * x for x in itertools.count())

d = {
"a": [-1, 2],
"b": [1, 2],
"c": [20, 20]
}
g = dict()
g2 = dict()
for letter, values in d.items():
    g[letter] = make_generator(values)
    g2[letter] = [values[0] * values[1] * x for x in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    for l, v in g.items():
        print(v.__next__())
print(g2)
```

It prints out:

```
0
0
0
-2
2
400
-4
4
800
{'a': [0, -2, -4], 'b': [0, 2, 4], 'c': [0, 400, 800]}
```

The point is that in your code all generators work with the same `values` variable in the local scope, so they all end up using the `values` from the last key in the dict.  In my version, each generator uses correct `values` because each generator is created in a separate scope.

This doesn't happen with the list comprehensions in `g2` because they are evaluated immediately with correct `values` in the local scope, and the generators are evaluated later when `values` has already been overwritten.